# Particular vector operation without loops

Tags: matlab

Given a vector `x1, x2, ..., xN`, I need to create a vector of `(x_i + x_j)` for `i = 1,...,N, j = i+1,...,N`.

E.g., for `x1, x2, x3, x4`:

```
x1+x2, x1+x3, x1+x4, x2+x3, x2+x4, x3+x4
```

How to do it without loops to get good performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C = combnk(v,k) returns a matrix containing all possible combinations of the elements of vector v taken k at a time.

So if you call

```
combnk(x,2)
```

you get

```
 x3     x4
 x2     x4
 x2     x3
 x1     x4
 x1     x3
 x1     x2
```

In case you rely on the order, which is now inverted, use `flipud`, then call `sum`

```
sum(flipud(combnk(x,2)),2)
```

Comment: Is this actually faster than a loop?

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Running some quick tests: no. I assumed `combnk` to be implemented in an efficient manner, but guess I was wrong.

Comment: `s = x+x.';s = s(~triu(true(numel(x))));` appears to be faster. For larger vectors `x` I would guess the looping method is best.